# Associative array in bash and for loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I am giving my first steps in bash and would like to create a associative array and iterate it. My instinct would be to do this:

```
declare -A FILES=(['SOURCE']='Source/Core/Core.js' ['DIST']='dist/Core.js')

for file in "${!FILES[@]}"; do
    echo $file - $FILES[$file]
done
```

But output is:

```
SOURCE - [SOURCE]
DIST - [DIST]
```

and no path as expected. What am I missing? and btw, is the `declare -A` required?

#### Demo: https://ideone.com/iQpjmj

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your expansions around braces. Without it, `$FILES` and `$file` would expand separately.

```
${FILES[$file]}
```

A good practice also is to place them around double quotes to prevent word splitting and possible pathname expansion:

```
echo "$file - ${FILES[$file]}"
```

Test:

```
$ declare -A FILES=(['SOURCE']='Source/Core/Core.js' ['DIST']='dist/Core.js')
$ for file in "${!FILES[@]}"; do echo "$file - ${FILES[$file]}"; done
SOURCE - Source/Core/Core.js
DIST - dist/Core.js
```

Comment: Thank you. One more step on my bash understanding.